# Comment creation date changing if try to edit a comment

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, comments

I'm working on a module for Drupal 7 and i came across a strange problem regarding comments. 
About the date of creation and modification of the comments.

If I try to edit a comment with the privilege `"Administer comments and comment settings"`  the created date in the `"comment"` database remains unchanged, while the changed date is modified .. so everything is right.

But if you are a registered user who does not have the privilege `"Administer comments and comment settings"`  and try to edit a comment, both dates (created and changed) will change

....even in the header of the comment the date is updated

`"Submitted by user on Wed, 19/02/2014 - 21:44"`

with the current date modified. 
How it is possible? this is a comment module issue?

I need that the creation date remains unchanged if a comment is edited. This without the administer privileges.

PS: I'm working on `hook_preprocess_comment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fought this problem not too long ago.

A colleague and I threw together a custom module to solve the problem. Here's the code currently working on our D7 (7.26) site:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Fixes a bug where Drupal doesn't retain the creation date of comments.
 */

 /**
  * Implements hook_comment_presave().
  */

 function comment_fix_comment_presave($comment) {
    $data = db_query('SELECT created FROM {comment} WHERE cid = :cid', 
        array(':cid' => $comment->cid))->fetchAll();

    if (!empty($data)) {
        $comment->created = $data[0]->created;
    }
 }
```